# Android - getAdapterPosition() returns -1 after deleting an item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The title says it all, I have a `RecyclerView` which is used to store values dynamically, but only one item at a time. The item contains 3 `TextViews`

When I add all the items normally, it works, but when I add x item, then remove the last one, and then click on "submit", the app crashes.

I do `removeAt(getAdapterPosition()` in the viewholder where `removeAt(int) is :

```
private void removeAt(int removePosition){
    grosirList.product_grosir_list.remove(removePosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(removePosition);
}
```

And submit button :

```
promoConfirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                if (postProductPromoAdapter.getGrosirList() == null){

                } else {
                    String grosirAddJson = gson.toJson(postProductPromoAdapter.getGrosirList());

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("grosirPromoPrice", grosirAddJson);
                    intent.putExtra("promoPrice", promoPriceET.getText().toString());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

`getGrosirList()` is

```
    public GrosirAddList getGrosirList(){
        if (mAwesomeValidation.validate()){
            return this.grosirList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Basically the submit button validates the `TextViews` and if it's validated, returns true.

This is where the error happens :

```
    minRangeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(!s.toString().equals("")){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(getAdapterPosition()).grosir_min = String.valueOf(s);
                    } else {
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(getAdapterPosition()).grosir_min = null; // Error happens here
                    }
                }
            });
```

I save user's input to an object inside the adapter to be retrieved later through `TextWatcher`

This is the error log :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
at xx.PostProductPromoAdapter$FiturPromoHolder$1.afterTextChanged(PostProductPromoAdapter.java:236)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7563)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3920)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3744)
at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.helper.SpanHelper.setColor(SpanHelper.java:22)
at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.ColorationValidator$1.execute(ColorationValidator.java:34)
at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.Validator.checkFields(Validator.java:76)
at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.ColorationValidator.trigger(ColorationValidator.java:25)
at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation.validate(AwesomeValidation.java:81)
at xx.getGrosirList(PostProductPromoAdapter.java:76)
at xx$3.onClick(PostProductPromoActivityRecycler.java:164)
```

Update :

I use this to check whether the items are valid :

```
public boolean filledCheck(int itemNumber){
    return this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() > 0
            && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_price != null
            && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_max != null
            && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_min != null;
}
```

And this to add the values to the `EditText`. Values is taken from user input using `TextWatcher`

```
    if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_min == null) {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).minRangeET.setText("");
    } else {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).minRangeET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_min);
    }

    if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_max == null) {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).maxRangeET.setText("");
    } else {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).maxRangeET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_max);
    }

    if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_price == null) {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceET.setText("");
    } else {
        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_price);
    }
```

Update, here's the whole Adapter code :

```
public boolean uploadProductLoading = true;

    private Context context;
    private AwesomeValidation mAwesomeValidation;

    public GrosirAddList grosirList = new GrosirAddList();

    private SharedPreferencesList sharedPreferencesList;
    private SharedPreferenceUtilities sharedPreferenceUtilities;
    private Utilities utilities;
    private UtilityUriHelper utilityUriHelper;

    // Allows to remember the last item shown on screen
    private int lastPosition = -1;


    // User information
    private String userIdString;
    private String userAliasString;
    private String userEmailString;
    private String loginSharedPrefsString;

    private String userId;
    private String userAlias;

    public PostProductPromoAdapter(Context context) {

        this.sharedPreferencesList = new SharedPreferencesList();
        this.sharedPreferenceUtilities = new SharedPreferenceUtilities();
        this.context = context;
        this.userIdString = sharedPreferencesList.userIDString;
        this.userAliasString = sharedPreferencesList.userAliasString;
        this.loginSharedPrefsString = sharedPreferencesList.loginSharedPreference;
        this.utilities = new Utilities();
        this.utilityUriHelper = new UtilityUriHelper();

        this.userId = sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(context, loginSharedPrefsString, userIdString);
        this.userAlias = sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(context, loginSharedPrefsString, userAliasString);
        this.mAwesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.COLORATION);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View productView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card, parent, false);
        return new FiturPromoHolder(productView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        // Animation, disabled for now
//        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);

        /*((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
//                notifyItemRemoved(position);
//                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
            }
        });*/



        /*((FiturPromoHolder)holder).minRangeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().equals("")){
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_min = String.valueOf(s);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_min = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).maxRangeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_max = String.valueOf(s);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_max = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_price = String.valueOf(s);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() != 0){
                        grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(position).grosir_price = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });*/

        int x = holder.getLayoutPosition();

        if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_min != null) {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).minRangeET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_min);
        } else {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).minRangeET.setText(null);
        }

        if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_max != null) {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).maxRangeET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_max);
        } else {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).maxRangeET.setText(null);
        }

        if(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_price != null) {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceET.setText(grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(x).grosir_price);
        } else {
            ((FiturPromoHolder)holder).grossPriceET.setText(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            viewToAnimate.clearAnimation();
//            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    public boolean filledCheck(int itemNumber){
        return this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() > 0
                && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_price.trim().length() > 0
                && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_max.trim().length() > 0
                && this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(itemNumber - 1).grosir_min.trim().length() > 0;
    }

    private void removeAt(int removePosition){
        grosirList.product_grosir_list.remove(removePosition);
//        notifyItemRemoved(removePosition);
//        notifyItemRangeChanged(removePosition, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyItemRemoved(removePosition);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
//        notifyItemRangeRemoved(removePosition, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());

//        notifyItemRangeChanged(removePosition, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
    }

    private void removeRange(int removePosition){
        int tempSize = grosirList.product_grosir_list.size();
        for (int i = removePosition; i < tempSize; i++){
            grosirList.product_grosir_list.remove(removePosition);
//            notifyItemRemoved(i);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
//        notifyItemRangeRemoved(removePosition, grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
//        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.size());
    }

    private void clearAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        viewToAnimate.clearAnimation();
    }

    public void addGrosirList(GrosirAddList dataset){
        this.grosirList.product_grosir_list.addAll(dataset.product_grosir_list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
//        notifyItemInserted(grosirList.product_grosir_list.size() - 1);
//        this.grosirList.add(grosirList.size(), dataset.product_grosir_list.get());
//        notifyItemInserted(grosirList.size() - 1);
    }

    public GrosirAddList getGrosirList(){
        if (mAwesomeValidation.validate()){
            return this.grosirList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
//        return this.grosirList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return grosirList.product_grosir_list.size();
    }

    public class FiturPromoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        Handler handler;
        RelativeLayout minRangeWrapper;
        OpenSansEditText minRangeET;
        RelativeLayout maxRangeWrapper;
        OpenSansEditText maxRangeET;
        RelativeLayout grossPriceWrapper;
        OpenSansEditText grossPriceET;
        OpenSansButton grossPriceDeleteBtn;

        public FiturPromoHolder(View promoView) {
            super(promoView);
            minRangeWrapper = (RelativeLayout)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_minRangeWrapper);
            minRangeWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);
            minRangeET = (OpenSansEditText)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_minRangeET);
            maxRangeWrapper = (RelativeLayout)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_maxRangeWrapper);
            maxRangeWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);
            maxRangeET = (OpenSansEditText)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_maxRangeET);
            grossPriceWrapper = (RelativeLayout)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_grossPriceWrapper);
            grossPriceWrapper.setOnClickListener(this);
            grossPriceET = (OpenSansEditText)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_grossPriceET);
            grossPriceDeleteBtn = (OpenSansButton)promoView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_upload_produk_fitur_promo_card_grossPriceDeleteBtn);
            grossPriceDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.setIsRecyclable(false);
            handler = new Handler();
            minRangeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(getLayoutPosition()).grosir_min = String.valueOf(s);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });

            maxRangeET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(getLayoutPosition()).grosir_max = String.valueOf(s);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });

            grossPriceET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            grosirList.product_grosir_list.get(getLayoutPosition()).grosir_price = String.valueOf(s);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });

            grossPriceET.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(grossPriceET));

            mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(minRangeET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Jumlah minimum tidak boleh kosong");
            mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(maxRangeET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Jumlah maximum tidak boleh kosong");
            mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(grossPriceET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Harga tidak boleh kosong");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.equals(grossPriceDeleteBtn)) {
                int removePosition = getAdapterPosition();
                try {
                    grosirList.product_grosir_list.remove(removePosition);
                    notifyItemRemoved(removePosition);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    minRangeET.setError(null);
                    maxRangeET.setError(null);
                    grossPriceET.setError(null);
//
                    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(minRangeET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Jumlah minimum tidak boleh kosong");
                    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(maxRangeET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Jumlah maximum tidak boleh kosong");
                    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(grossPriceET, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, "Harga tidak boleh kosong");
                }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            } else if(v.equals(minRangeWrapper)) {
                minRangeET.requestFocusFromTouch();
            } else if(v.equals(maxRangeWrapper)) {
                maxRangeET.requestFocusFromTouch();
            } else if(v.equals(grossPriceWrapper)) {
                grossPriceET.requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully the mistake isn't so stupid.....

Comment: If you read the documentation, it returns -1 when `notifyDataSetChanged` or any of the similar methods are called. [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition%28%29).

Comment: Whoa, so, how to handle the `TextWatcher` after removing a value? I need to change the value of each `EditText` to the one in the list, but after removing one item, the position doesn't `update`.. It still go to position 1 (the item removed was at position 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's due to the animation while we use `notifyItemRemoved()`. So during that animation delay, if we instantly call `getAdapterPosition()` method, then it'll return `-1`. I had the same issue while I repeatedly remove more than one items instantly, I got this exception.

Possible solution:
You can just first check position first, like below code:

```
private void removeAt(int removePosition){
    if(removePosition == -1)    
        return;
    grosirList.product_grosir_list.remove(removePosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(removePosition);
}
```

This is a late answer, but Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Hahaha a late answer indeed but I got it working by now :D in the end, I check whether the `removePosition` is in between 0 to size of dataset - 1. By doing that, I dodged the error and I think it's still working well till now lol

Comment: Umm this answer didn't solve my problem, I solved it by myself by adding validation whether 0 <= position < mdataset.size().. But because it is actually mostly the same as what I did, I shall accept it!

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for this. First of all, check your `getItemCount()` in your Adapter, make sure it returns the size of your stack. Second, instead of `notifyItemRemoved()` notify your adapter that the stack has changed with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

If above those not solve your issue please post your Adapter code, and every code that you work around with your stack. Problems should be rising from one of those points.

Best,
Renç.

Comment: My `getItemCount()` returned the size of my stack which is `return grosirList.product_grosir_list.size();` I've done `notifyItemRemoved()` then `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and also either one of them. And about the Adapter code which work around with my stack.. I think I've posted all of them, let me check and post any unposted code

Comment: I posted 2 snippets, when I moved the textwatcher into `onBindViewHolder` and takes position needed from the parameter, it says invalid index, index is 0, but size is 0, gonna make a condition `if size == 0`

Comment: Nahhh, tried doing that and got index 1, size 1 instead.. I am now at loss

Comment: Could you post the code of entire classes which u use for this operation?

Comment: You mean the entire adapter class or the entire activity?