# Error on removing item from RecyclerView, Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am looking at my recycler view, I want to be able to delete items.

When I swipe to delete I get this error.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=-1

I presume it isn't getting the position when I swipe

How can this be fixed?

Here is the code I use in the activity.

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
    messages_recycler_view.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MessagesListVC)
        val topSpacePaddingDecoration = TopSpacingItemDecoration(30)
        addItemDecoration(topSpacePaddingDecoration)
        messagesAdapter = MessagesRecyclerAdaptor()
        adapter = messagesAdapter


        val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback(this@MessagesListVC) {

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                messagesAdapter = MessagesRecyclerAdaptor()
                adapter = messagesAdapter
                (adapter as MessagesRecyclerAdaptor).removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
            }
        }
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(messages_recycler_view)
    }
}
```

And this is the remove function in the recycler adaptor.

```
fun removeAt(position: Int) {
    println("Tony the items count is {${messagesInfo.size}")
    messagesInfo.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    println("Tony the new data is $messagesInfo")
    println("Tony the items count is {${messagesInfo.size}")
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to incorporate the answer, as it would mean future readers won't see the actual problem that has been solved.

Comment: @RobCo I didn't edit the question to the answer I edited the answer based on a comment in the answer by the same person who gave the answer, the question still remains as it was without 2 lines that dint really have anything to do with the problem as I noticed it as an error just after posting. the answer was to add a check before running the method, which shows in the answer and not the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your code but one thing I notice is that you create a new adapter everytime you swipe. I'm not sure why you would do that. And I also don't know if it has anything to do with the crash you are getting. But wouldn't it maybe work when leaving out the first two lines in `onSwiped`? so that becomes

```
override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                println("Tony the int position is $position")

                if (position > 0) {
                    (messagesAdapter.removeAt(position))
                }
            }
```

Comment: I seen this error just after posting, I have removed these lines and still get the same error, I also created a val of Int and assigned it to viewHolder.adaptor position and then added a print, it returns -1, its like it isn't getting the position of the cell when swiped.

Comment: Does it maybe register multiple swipes short after another? I read that it can return -1 when it's still in the process of handling another notifyItemRemoved. Maybe just saying to not do anything when it's -1 would solve it for you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908448/android-getadapterposition-returns-1-after-deleting-an-item for example

Comment: Ok that seemed to work for Me, I added a check that if position is >0 then perform the function, I will edit your answer on here to show it and accept it as the answer. Thank you for your time on it